# Box Plot implementation in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Referring to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502 I tried implementing Box plots which reads data from JSON. The code to read from csv is

```
d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, csv) {
var data = [];

csv.forEach(function(x) {
var e = Math.floor(x.Expt - 1),
    r = Math.floor(x.Run - 1),
    s = Math.floor(x.Speed),
    d = data[e];
if (!d) d = data[e] = [s];
else d.push(s);
if (s > max) max = s;
if (s < min) min = s;
});
```

csv data:

```
Expt,Run,Speed
1,1,850
1,2,740
1,3,900
1,4,1070
1,5,930
1,6,850
1,7,950
1,8,980
1,9,980
1,10,880
```

I replaced the csv to json as follows:

```
d3.json("morley.json", function(json) {
var data = json.data;
var ChartData = [];// Should Contain speed values
data.forEach(function(d,i){
  chartData.push(d.Speed);
});   
var min = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.Speed});
var max = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.Speed})
```

My json is:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Expt": 1,
        "Run": 2,
        "Speed": 850
    },
    {
        "Expt": 1,
        "Run": 3,
        "Speed": 740
    },
    {
        "Expt": 1,
        "Run": 4,
        "Speed": 900
    },
    {
        "Expt": 1,
        "Run": 5,
        "Speed": 1070
    },
    {
        "Expt": 1,
        "Run": 6,
        "Speed": 930
    }]
}
```

when we call d3.box method

```
 var chart = d3.box()
            .whiskers(iqr(1.5))
            .width(width)
            .height(height); 

d3.box = function() {

// For each small multipleâ€¦
function box(g) {
g.each(function(d, i) {
    alert(d);
  d = d.map(value).sort(d3.ascending); // error at this line saying object dont have method map
  alert(d);
  var g = d3.select(this),
      n = d.length,
      min = d[0],
      max = d[n - 1];
```

I dont get the error when i read from csv but when i read from JSON i get this object has no method map error. What is the difference?

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this

```
{
     "Speed": [850, 740, ...],
     "Expt": [1, 1, ...],
     "Run": [1, 2, ...]
}
```

It is the only way `json.speed` makes sense and `d3.min/max` returns the expected result, if you drop the second argument.

With your data structure, to get the minimum speed the correct command is

```
d3.min(json.data, function(d) { return d.Speed; });
```

Comment: It was my posting mistake. problem is not for calculating min max values. I have updated the post.

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out that when changing the data structure you should also check the methods you apply to it (e.g the min and max). It seems that if you organize your JSON in the same manner to [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-parse) you won't run into trouble, as it will have the same structure as the formatted csv file.

Comment: Your suggestion helped. With some changes I am now able to render the box plot, reading data from JSON. Now I want to add y axis to this plot. Will it be possible to create another svg for axis and relate it to the existing plot somehow so that it matches the exact scale? or can I use the same svg element and add axis to it? I am wondering how to start.

Comment: You definitely don't want to create a new svg, but it's real piece of cake adding a y axis on the same svg. I strongly suggest you to check [this tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes) as it explains thoroughly how to add axes to a visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
    var data = json.data; 
    var ChartData = [];// Should Contain speed values
    data.forEach(function(d,i){
     chartData.push(d.Speed);
    });   
   var min = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.Speed});
   var max = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.Speed})
```

It's work for me:

```
  var jsondata = json.data;
    var chartData = [];// Should Contain speed values
    jsondata.forEach(function(d,i){
        var e = Math.floor(d.Expt - 1),
                r = Math.floor(d.Run - 1),
                s = Math.floor(d.Speed),
                d = chartData[e];
            if (!d) d = chartData[e] = [s];
            else d.push(s);
            if (s > max) max = s;
            if (s < min) min = s;
    });
```

I hope I've helped.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!